# Two Basic Python Dictionary Questions

Tags: python

Question 1.)

```
for a,a in dict.items():
    print a
```

Why does the above print the value, and if i print a,a - obviously both values are printed twice. If I had typed for a,b I would be iterating (key,value) pairs so I would logically think I am now iterating over (key,key) pairs and would therefore print key rather than value. Sorry for the basic questions just playing around in interpreter and trying to figure stuff out.

Question 2.)

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    print "%s is the key that corresponds to the value %s"%(key,value)
```

The above example makes sense to me, but why does:

```
for key in dict.items():
    print "%s is the key that corresponds to the value %s"%(key)
```

produce the same result?  Is it because even though we aren't unpacking the tuple into two separate variables in the `for` statement, it is returned as `(key,value)` in the string formatter through the `key` call - basically making `%(key)` = `(key,value)`?

Comment: For Q1, it's a behavior like `a, a = 1, 2` which makes `a=1` and then `a=2`, so finally `a` is 2.

Comment: That comment (also pointed out by @James below) was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1:**

Consider the following:

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> xs = d.items()
>>> a, a = xs[0]
>>> print a, a
1 1
```

This is effectively what is happening. You are unpacking each `(key, value)` pair into `(a, a)` effectively ending up with `(value, value)`. The reference to the key is lost.

This is the same as:

```
>>> a, a = 1, 2
>>> print a, a
2, 2
```

What happens here in the interpreter during the unpacking:

1. `a` becomes `1`.
2. `a` becomes `2`.

**Q2:**

Consider the following:

```
>>> a, b = ("a", 1)
>>> print "%s=%s" % (a, b)
a, 1
>>> x = ("a", 1)
>>> print "%s=%s" % x
a, 1
```

The two are effectively the same. Since your string interpolation is expecting a tuple of two both `(a, b)` and `x` (*a tuple of 2 values*) effectively satisfies this.

Answer (score 0):

You right. `key` is now tuple `(k,v)` and `"..."%` expect tuple with arguments. And `((k,v))` ( in `".." % ((k,v))` ) doesn't give "tuple in tuple" but only "single-level" tuple - like `(1)` doesn't give tuple but integer `1` - so you have `"..." % (k,v)`

Answer (score 0):

```
d={1:2,4:5,6:7,8:8}
for a,a in d.items():
    print(a,a)
```

In dictionary ,
`a,a` runs with `(key,value)`
And ends up with `(value,value)`

Output:

```
Starts with (1,2) ends with (2,2)
Starts with (4,5) ends with (5,5)
Starts with (6,7) ends with (7,7)
Starts with (8,8) ends with (8,8)
```

So Actual Output:

```
2 2
5 5
7 7
8 8
```